# why my Cron script running just once?

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run a simple python script using cron commands. I have written code to run my python script at every 1 minute and write the output to the text file, but it runs once and update text file once.
Below is the my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Created on Thu Apr 28 15:49:19 2016

@author: rajababu
"""

target=open('/home/rajababu/Desktop/output.txt', 'w')
target.write("print")
target.write("\n")
```

and below is my **cron command** :

```
 */1 * * * * python /home/rajababu/Desktop/cronjob.py
```

i have searched online for the exact reason but could not find anything.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: doing `target.close()` is good practice after you finish working with your file, so that other programs can now access it. (including notepad/whatever)

Comment: Your cron is indeed running every minute, it's just that your python code is grabbing the file and overwriting it, rather than appending.

Comment: thank you @AmitGold  thanks for your suggestion, will keep in mind.

Comment: The pythonic way is to use `with target = open(...):`. Then it will be closed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's only running once? The `'w'` flag will open the file for writing, clearing the existing contents. All you'll ever see is a single `'print'` line. Change it to `'a'` and it should append rather than overwrite.

Comment: thanks you, it worked.
i need to revise the basic concepts.